# is there any php-pgsql package avaliable for any linux OS versions?

Tags: php, linux, postgresql, centos, redhat

I need to know whether there is a php_pgsql.dll equivalent package for linux OS or not. I have searched in web but i could find only the pdo-pgsql package. I require php_pgsql driver as in  windows.

Comment: What flavour and version of Linux? You're wanting the pg_* functions?

Comment: i actualy tried  to get php-pgsql package for redhat 6.8. but i didnt get

Comment: ...tried what? I didn't mention anything for you to try...

Comment: we are using pgsql driver rather than pdo.

Comment: What version of Linux... otherwise I'm just going to tell you to compile PHP yourself manually.

Comment: I am using Redhat linux 6.8.  project developed in codeigniter platform with postgresql backend

Comment: *facepalm* you already said. I'm an idiot :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using RedHat, you can use the [Remi repo](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/Config-en), which includes builds for all the latest versions of PHP.

The package you want is called `php-pgsql`

```
yum install php-pgsql
```

Comment: when issue the command  yum install php56 show an error  **No package php56 available**  .

Comment: Remi's packages are all named `php-`. So try `yum install php php-pgsql`